# WordPress Theme Appearing Incorrectly in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I'm working on http://pizzli.com/toothworks and the site appears beautifully in FireFox, but when I open it up in Internet Explorer, it displays completely messed up. Any support would be appreciated.

Comment: three cheers for the bane of a web developer's existence!

Comment: @ScottM. Please keep comments relevant.

Comment: Please pick out one issue with the site and display the corresponding code that you think is the cause. We dont want to look through all of your code to find the problem.

Comment: @user1249318 I checked your site in IE7 through IE10, Firefox, and Chrome, and didn't see any substantial differences. It may be worth noting I was emulating IE7-IE9 from IE10, but still didn't see what would be described as a site "messed up". Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Jonathan I think it is relevant. He (or she) is not the only one who has issues with internet explorer. Having a sense of humor and informing them this is a common problem at the same time is certainly relevant.

Comment: @ScottM. Our involvement should move the question towards a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Start by validating the page, then you will find some errors in the code that you should correct:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpizzli.com%2Ftoothworks%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

The first error is in the script, so you don't have to bother about that right now.

You have some break tags and image tags that you haven't closed, that would be easy to fix.

You have a style tag in the middle of the page, that should be in the head tag.

You seem to have unmatched starting and ending tags for a div tag somewhere, they don't add up at the end.